# Need to set ssm:PutParameter rights in my AWS instance in order to reset my Admin password

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

AWS novice here! Having changed the Admin password on my AWS Windows Server instance, I went to log on again a week later and found that my password was not what I thought it was. Apparently the only way to reset the Admin password is using AWS System Manager. I created my policy OK, but when I ran it, I got the error

```
Make sure instance xxxxxxx has ssm:PutParameter rights to parameter.
```

However, this seems to be the first step in the sample policy I copied:

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17", 
  "Statement": [ 
    { 
      "Effect": "Allow", 
      "Action": [ 
      "ssm:PutParameter" 
      ], 
      "Resource": [ 
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/EC2Rescue/Passwords/i-*" 
        ] 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but is that policy attached to the role in the instance profile of the instance?

Comment: I believe so, but the UI for System Manager is so arcane it's hard to tell. I'll check that

Comment: Seems to be. I've drilled down from the instance and found the policy, so it looks like it's attached to the instance